# Disabling Commands on guild Discord JS COMMANDO

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have a question. Does Discord JS Commando disable command only on guild or globally?

Comment: Can you please add more information like command and if you're getting any error. You could even try yourself to verify this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/commands/builtins) (Command state (commands)):

**disable (commands:disable)**

Disables a command/group in the current guild if the user is an admin or the bot owner. If used in a DM (direct message), it disables the command/group globally by default if the user is the bot owner.